# Where can I find lists of homophonic heterographs that overlapped accidentally?

Tags: historical-linguistics

1. Is [homophonic heterograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterography_and_homography) the correct term? I know that it doesn't restrict them to this question's only target: chance overlaps. See [*Linguistics: An Introduction to Language and Communication* (2017 7 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/026253326X), p. 306.

> In
>   establishing genetic relationships among languages, then, one must exclude words that may have been borrowed and are therefore not part of a
>   common inheritance. [...]
>
> #### Chance Overlap in Sound and Meaning
>
> The fact that languages often have similarities in sound structure and
>   have words for common objects yields a significant probability that there
>   will be accidental overlaps in sound-meaning correspondences between
>   them. For example, all languages have a low vowel (such as *a*), and most
>   have *i* and/or *u* vowels; most languages have *t, k*, and *p* and the nasal
>   consonants *n* and *m*.

2. Where can I find such lists: see my red "side highlight" beneath? It's from
   John McWhorter [PhD Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter)'s [*The Power of Babel* (2003)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006052085X), pp. 226-227.

> [image]

Comment: As noted, they're not usually homophones; just similar enough in pronunciation to impress somebody who's looking for correspondences. There are never regular sound correspondences in these lists, and there are always differences. To see the lists, check the bibliographies. And read Trask's _Historical Linguistics_ -- he gives lots of lists of various kinds.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate

Answer (score 1):

You have provided one such list, from McWhorter. [This page](https://www.zompist.com/chance.htm) gives another set of Quechua-Semitic chance correspondences. [Here](http://web.ku.edu/~pyersqr/Ling107/history.pdf) are some Algonquian-Scots pairs, and [some Hawaiian-Classical Greek pairs](http://www.ling.cam.ac.uk/li11/li11_lecture13.pdf). "Homophonic heterograph" does not seem to refer to what you intend, and isn't a term in linguistics: these are called "chance correspondences".